# SQL Query - merge 2 column results seperated by comma if another 2 column are equal

Tags: sql, merge

I need help on a SQL query to do the following-->
If Column results are equal except sku_num , then sku_num are combined and separated by a comma. This example only has 2 results but there could be more than 2 results. thanks in advance

Result that I have

![enter image description here][1]

Results that I need

[![Result that I need][2]][2]

SQL Code

```
SELECT chassis_option.chassis_id          AS [Chassis ID], 
       chassis_option.module_id           AS [Module ID], 
       chassis_option.internal_name       AS [Option Internal Name], 
       chassis_option.global_option_id    AS [Global Option ID], 
       chassis_option.option_code         AS [Regional Option ID], 
       chassis_option.external_name       AS [Option External Name], 
       chassis_option.current_status_code AS [Option Status], 
       chassis_option_item.sku_num 
FROM   chassis_option 
       INNER JOIN chassis_option_item 
               ON chassis_option.chassis_id = chassis_option_item.chassis_id 
                  AND chassis_option.module_id = chassis_option_item.module_id 
                  AND chassis_option.option_code = 
                      chassis_option_item.option_code 
WHERE  ( chassis_option.global_option_id = N'GJP0LCK' )
```

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using?

Comment: The RDBMS is MySQL

Comment: Please add mysql tag in the question and look for my answer below that 
should work.

Comment: group_concat(sku_num SEPARATOR ',') sku_num is causing an error

Incorrect syntax near 'SEPARATOR'.

Comment: try this: `group_concat(sku_num)`

Comment: still not working...

'group_concat' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Your query is SQL not MySQL. That's why GROUP_CONCAT doesn't exist.

Comment: yes you are right. Can anyone help build the query for SQL

Comment: "SQL" is a query language, not a database product. Every relational database is a "SQL database". Please tell us which database product you are using ("SQL" is **not** the answer to that question)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT <list all columns>, group_concat(sku_num) sku_num
FROM tableName
GROUP BY <list all columns>
```

SQL Server

```
SELECT 
    <list all columns>, 
    STRING_AGG(sku_num, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sku_num) AS [sku_num]
FROM 
    tableName
GROUP BY 
    <list all columns>
```

P.S. List of columns in `SELECT` and in `GROUP BY` should be same.

Comment: This is only for MySQL, can it be built for SQL